# Should I put my html directly on the php or read it from a file

Tags: php, basic-authentication

I am very new to php and have a doubt regarding best practices. I want to know if, when returning html from php, I should include the html directly into the php file, inside an echo statement or load it from an external file. If I do load it from an external file, will there be a disk operation every time a user loads the page?

I don't know whether this is relevant, but the context is authentication. I want to send a Basic Authentication request to a php file, which will return a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix PHP and HTML in same script page. While PHP intepreter find the code within PHP tag it will take that as PHP. Others will be displayed directly. See the following example.

```
<?php
$header = "PHP html Mix";
?>
<h1><?php echo $header; ?></h1>
<p>You can use php and html as mix. no need to echo static elements.</p>
```

Copy and past on a php file then run and see.

- First we create php tag and assign a string to php variable.
- Then we create just few html tags and text.
- Between `<h1>` tag again a php tag introduced to echo the string.

If you want to put whole html inside `if` or `for` that also possible like follows.

```
<?php if($display==1){ ?>
<h2>Write whatever html within these start and close php tag.</h2>
<strong>no need to echo this in php</strong>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What if I want to put the whole page inside an if statement (to be displayed only if an authentication succeeds?

Comment: @rvcam it would be better to have your page, but at the top of the file check for the authentication, and redirect if authentication failed

Comment: @Bluehound But, if I did that, anyone could get to my page without authentication, if only they knew the url, right?

Comment: @rvcam that's why you have to use a method that the user can't see such as $_POST or $_SESSION. The $_GET method (aka the url) can be seen by users and is best suited for insecure data.

Comment: @rvcam: Check the edited answer. if statement also possible.

Comment: @Bluehound Once they get to the page, won't they be able to see the url in the navbar? Then wouldn't the be able to go to that page directly afterwards without passing through the authentication page?

Comment: @rvcam if it is in a php tag at the top of the page, yes they can TRY to go the page, but every time the php tag at the top of the page that checks for authentication will be executed server side and redirect them if they can't be authenticated.

Comment: Thank you, anonymous, that was precisely the answer I wanted, though Bluehound presented a more efficient method of which I hadn't thought.

Answer (score 2):

Having the server access multiple files upon a web request probably does increase disk activity but it needn't be a concern the overhead is small compared to db queries etc.

Take a look at wordpress... it probably works its way through 20 files or more before rendering any output.

I personally think it is good practice to keep your markup templates, even when interpolated with numerous `<?=$var?>`  tags separate from your files which process logic and db queries

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in using PHP with HTML is to combine PHP code inside `<?php` and `?>` delimiters with pure (static) HTML. For instance, consider the example below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
        http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>The current date: <?php echo(date("Y-m-d")); ?>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So it's supposed to be used in that way whenever possible, preferably with an addition of an architectural design pattern like MVC (Model-View-Controller).

Comment: What if I want to put the whole page inside an if statement (to be displayed only if an authentication succeeds?

Comment: @rvcam: You would use a controller for logic and include appropriate PHP files depending on the outcome inside it. Of course, those PHP files can contain pure HTML code as well as PHP code within the above-mentioned delimiters.